# How to increase the speed from Interspire to postfix MTA?

Tags: postfix

Currently I'm getting a speed of 5 emails /sec from Interspire to postfix server. I tuned each and every parameter to the max level, even then didn't get any increase in speed.

Here I'm pasting my config

Postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
default_process_limit = 1000
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.regex
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = ****************
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = **********, 127.0.0.0/8, ***********
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
qmgr_message_active_limit = 100000
qmgr_message_recipient_limit = 100000
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 0
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Interspire Support told me that the error could be in postfix configuration. Is there any way to increase rate of accepting messages in postfix. Please give suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to tell from that output, but nothing stands out at present.  Can you format it a bit cleaner?  The speed will be limited by hardware of course, as well as any policy checks(such as running mail through Amavisd or post-grey), re-writes, etc.

Comment: There is no spam filters. and the hardware spec as follows:-
4 core, 24GB RAM , Xeon Processor.